# Using StringBuilder instead of toString()

Tags: java, tostring, stringbuilder

The comments show the toString() method originally but I want to change it to a string builder method. I have a couple of these but this is the simplest one. You can see what I have tried. Thank you in advance.

```
public StringBuilder toString() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append("Data in Kennel " + name + " is:");
    //String results = "Data in Kennel " + name + " is:";

    for (Animal d : dogs) {
        //results = results + d.toString() + "\n";
        str.append(d.toString() + "\n");
    }

    return str;
   //return result;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this method?

Comment: The method is used to print out all dogs data that is stored in an arraylist.

Comment: @robertM: you should specify the exact problem you have when posting a question. This avoids that we have to guess.

Comment: If this is the original code it has StringBuilder all over it now.  I don't think you're showing us either what you want to do or anything that worked before.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Eran it will be eventually be used to print all animals in alpha order.

Answer (score 3):

If this is for a `toString()` override or even if it's not, then it **must** return a String, not a StringBuilder. Else it's not a true override, and it shouldn't even compile since the method signature is the same as Object's toString() but with a different return type.

Instead, sure use a StringBuilder internally within the method body, but return the StringBuilder's `toString()`.

e.g.,

```
@Override // this must return String
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.append("Data in Kennel " + name + " is:");

    for (Animal d : dogs) {
        strBuilder.append(d.toString() + "\n");
    }

    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be strBuilder.toString();

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!  I'm sorry to everyone else if I was not clear

Comment: @robertM: you're welcome. I think that the issue is that you didn't give us any context to your question. Consider telling more details in the future so that we can clearly understand what you're asking without guessing or repeatedly asking for clarification. The [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section will tell you more about how to ask questions that can get decent quick responses. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to make a method like `Object's` `toString()` which returns a `StringBuilder`. Don't do this. Use `StringBuilder` and you can convert it to a `String` using `toString()`.

```
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder("SampleString");
String str = strb.toString();
```